# What can I delete from a live DVD ISO?

Tags: usb-installation

I want burn the latest release to a USB but the only one I have available at the moment is 1.8 GB and the ISO is 1.95.

I can find a bigger USB but I'd like to get on with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Delete whatever you don't need. :~)

Comment: [Much smaller](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) .iso files are available. However, these are NOT recommended for first-time installers -- they expect you to know what you are doing.

Comment: Get rid of the desktop, who needs more than command line.   We can't know what you want, need or won't need.  If we answer, our suggestions may make no sense to you (you could be someone who wants a mouse-driver gui - yuk!)

Comment: If you are prepared to create a new iso file, remaster the system after removing some program packages, yes you can do it, but it is difficult compared to selecting an Ubuntu family flavour with an iso file that is small enough. I suggest that you try Lubuntu and Xubuntu (both 19.04 iso files approx 1.5 Gibibytes) and after that stay with the flavour that you like best. There are also beta versions of 19.10 that will be released officially until later in this month (October).-- Or use the Ubuntu netboot iso file as suggested already.

Comment: @Gordon Harvey Editing an ISO file is not recommended for beginners. A) Can you move files off the USB to a drive on a PC to make more space? B) If not, then sudodus' idea of using a different 'flavour' http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours of Ubuntu is good. The ISO for Budgie http://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads is 1.6GiB , Xubuntu http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/18.04/release/ is 1.3 GiB , and Lubuntu https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ is 1.1 GiB . All are supported here, all have Ubuntu as their foundation, all will run Ubuntu apps, just with a different look-and-feel.

Comment: As others have mentioned, customizing the ISO is not a beginners task, but if you are up for it, we have a good step-by-step guide on how to do this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm not a beginner, but I'll gladly take the easier way and use a lighter flavour.